# Multinomial Distribution - Compute the probability of the sample containing 6 with grade

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

Consider a class with 100 students enrolled. Suppose that 30 achieved a mark over
70%,60
achieved between 50-69% and 10 achieved
0−49%
. Let's take a randomly selected sample of 12 of these students for course moderation purposes such that they can be considered independent of each other.

**(a)** Write down the probability distribution function of the number receiving each of the three type of grades
$X=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Remember to note the constraints on the sample space.

**(b)** Compute the probability of the sample containing 6 with grade A, 4 with grade
B+ and 2 with grade C

**(c)** Compute the probability of the sample containing 6 with grade A

---

Could someone help with part (c) of this question?

I was taking the following approach but am unsure if it's correct. It seems wrong to me and I feel as though I'm missing logic.

$P(X_1 = 6) = \frac{12!}{6!\cdot 0!\cdot 6!} \cdot 0.3^6 \cdot 0.6^0 \cdot 0.1^6 = .00005$

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the sum of all probabilities where $x_1=6$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3=12$. This is

$$P(X_1=6)=\sum\limits_{x_2=0}^{6}  \frac{12!}{6!\cdot x_2!\cdot (12-6-x_2)!}\cdot 0.3^6\cdot 0.6^{x_2}\cdot 0.1^{12-6-x_2}$$

For instance: If $x_2=2$ and the given $x_1=6$, then $x_3=12-6-2=4$. The sum is $12$. You add up all combinations, where $x_2+x_3=6$.

$$=\frac{12!/6!}{6!}\cdot 0.3^6\cdot 0.1^{6}\cdot \sum\limits_{x_2=0}^{6}\frac{6!}{x_2!\cdot (12-6-x_2)!}\cdot 6^{x_2}$$

$$=\frac{12!}{6!\cdot 6!}\cdot 0.3^6\cdot 0.1^{6}\cdot \sum\limits_{x_2=0}^{6} \binom{6}{x_2}\cdot 6^{x_2}\cdot 1^{6-x_2}$$

For the sum you can use the binomial theorem.

**Update**

More general: For arbitrary $p_i,x_1$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} x_i=n$ the probability is

$$P(X_1=x_1)=\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdot (n-x_1)!}\cdot p_1^{x_1}\cdot (p_2+p_3)^{n-x_1},$$

where $p_2+p_3=1-p_1$.Therefore the marginal pmf is distributed as $X_1\sim \textrm{Bin}(n,p_1)$.